# Sum mixed columns in R: sum integer cells, concatenate character cells

Tags: r

I have a mixed character and integer dataframe in R:

```
     NAME     ID       X       Y      Z
1    apple    a123p   1.0     2.0    3.0
2    orange   o483e   4.0     5.0    6.0
3    grape    g302e   1.0     1.5    2.0
```

where the only the column `Name` contains characters, and the rest of the columns (`ID, X, Y, Z`) contain integers.  I would like to add certain columns together: summing the integers, and joining the characters.

Desired output if apple + orange are added:

```
     NAME            ID              X       Y      Z
 1   apple          a123p           1.0     2.0    3.0
 2   orange         o483e           4.0     5.0    6.0
 3   grape          g302e           1.0     1.5    2.0
 4   apple_orange   a123p_o483      5.0     7.0    9.0
```

Is this possible? I tried looking up tutorials for `dplyr` and `aggregate` but encountered errors and confusion. I'm not sure if there's something specific to my needs.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the logic for adding two things - why apple and orange? Do you want to write a function where name can be specificed as arguments? and why is the output becoming a new row in the same data frame?

Comment: (1) are you sure `ID` is integer? it doesn't look that way ... (2) Same Q as @vagabond, who beat me to it slightly ...

Comment: It is not necessary for the output to be a new row in the same data frame, it can be in a new df.  In the real data, I have related items (ie: version1, version2, version3) and want to get the sum of different combinations of these items. But I want to keep track of which two versions were added together: ie: v1+v3, v1+v2, v2+v3.

Comment: @BenBolker - sapply(df, mode) reveals that ID is numeric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an index of rows where 'NAME' is either 'apple' or 'orange'

```
i1 <- df1$NAME %in% c("apple", "orange")
```

then find the integer and character columns

```
i2 <- sapply(df1, is.numeric)
```

and use the indexes to subset the rows, columns, loop through the non-integer columns, `paste` them together, similarly, loop through the integer column, get the `sum`, append the `list`s together with `c` and `rbind` with the original dataset

```
rbind(df1, c(lapply(df1[i1, !i2], paste, collapse="-"), lapply(df1[i1, i2], sum)))
#          NAME          ID X   Y Z
#1        apple       a123p 1 2.0 3
#2       orange       o483e 4 5.0 6
#3        grape       g302e 1 1.5 2
#4 apple-orange a123p-o483e 5 7.0 9
```

Comment: Running in to a "invalid factor level, NA generated" error. I think there must be something wrong with my numeric columns.  This does work to concatenate the character columns though!

Comment: @moxed In my example, I used the 'NAME' and 'ID' as `character` class.  You can do one thing before applying the code `df1[1:2] <- lapply(df1[1:2], as.character)`

Comment: this works PERFECT. Thank you! Newbie question/curiosity: if I didn't care about concatenating strings, and just wanted the summed values, would I just use the lapply function?

Comment: @moxed Yes, you could just use the `lapply(df1[i1, i2], sum)`, but I am not sure what value you would have for the NAME, ID if you are `rbind`ing it

Comment: @arkun - is it always necessary to do the indexing? Thank you again, this is so helpful.  Do you know a good book / site for basic data manipulation of dataframes in R, that I could review (and not bother you with so many questions).

Comment: @moxed In the conventional sense, indexing is `data[row, column]` so whatever value or sequence of values you mention in those index, gets filtered out